# Mallet in R regex error :java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters

Tags: regex, r, rjava, topic-modeling, mallet

Ive been following the tutorial on how to use mallet in R to create topic models. My text file has 1 sentence per line. It looks like this and has about 50 sentences.

```
Thank you again and have a good day :).
This is an apple.
This is awesome!
LOL!
i need 2.
.
.
.
```

This is my code:

```
Sys.setenv(NOAWT=TRUE)

#setup the workspace
# Set working directory
dir<-"/Users/jxn"
Dir <- "~/Desktop/Chat/malletR/text" # adjust to suit
require(mallet)
documents1 <- mallet.read.dir(Dir)
View(documents1)
stoplist1<-mallet.read.dir("~/Desktop/Chat/malletR/stoplists")
View(stoplist1)
**mallet.instances <- mallet.import(documents1$id, documents1$text, "~/Desktop/Chat/malletR/stoplists/en.txt", token.regexp ="\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")**
```

Everything works except for the last line of the code

```
**`**mallet.instances <- mallet.import(documents1$id, documents1$text, "~/Desktop/Chat/malletR/stoplists/en.txt", token.regexp ="\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")**`**
```

I keep getting this error :

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
```

According to the package, this is how the function should be:

```
mallet.instances <- mallet.import(documents$id, documents$text, "en.txt",
                    token.regexp = "\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")
```

I believe it has something to do with the token.regexp argument as
`documents1 <- mallet.read.dir(Dir)` works just fine which means that the first 3 arguments supplied to mallet.instances was correct.

This is a link to the git repo that i was following the tutorial from. 
https://github.com/shawngraham/R/blob/master/topicmodel.R

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the problem is with your text file.  I have encountered the same error and resolved it by using the `as.character()` function as follows:

`mallet.instances <- mallet.import(as.character(documents$id),
    as.character(documents$text), 
    "en.txt", 
    FALSE, 
    token.regexp="\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")`

Comment: Having the same problem but didn't work the solution.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228750/rjava-jcall-issue wonder if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you converted the id field also to character ? It is easy to overlook the advice and leave it as an integer.

```
Also there is a typo in the code sample: the backslashes have to be escaped:
    token.regexp = "\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}"
This usually occurs because the html text editor eats up one backslash.
```