# R mallet error in jcall:java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters

Tags: r, mallet

I am using mallet in R, It was working fine until I install devtools. After that I start getting following error which I never got.

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No suitable method for the given parameters
```

error get thrown:

```
documents <- mallet.read.dir("~/mytopicsfiles/")
mallet.instances <- mallet.import(documents$id, documents$text, "~/stopwords.txt", token.regexp ="\\p{L}[\\p{L}\\p{P}]+\\p{L}")
```

After searching in, I found someone has answered exact question and answer given in that question did't actually work. Since its not an accepted answer not sure if the answer is correct.

[rjava .jcall issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228750/rjava-jcall-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Did you find the answer? 
You should make `documents$id` and `documents$text` as character.

`as.character(documents$id)`, `as.character(documents$text)`